# Keyup event in select2 searchbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I can't seem to find a keyup event for the searchbox in select2. I've tried this:

```
$('select2.search__field').on("keyup", function ()
{
...
});
```

and alot of stuff, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried searching for some documentation? http://select2.github.io/select2/#documentation

Comment: I looked at their website, and they only had select2:open, select, unselect but not a keyup event. The link you wrote seems to be a documentation for 3.5.2, do you know where I can find the documentation for 4.0 or is the "examples" page on their website all there is?

Comment: Yes, it seems like they removed the old event select2-loaded which would work in my case, so the question is how are you supposed to do this in select2 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch key events like :

- keydown.
- keypress.
- keyup.
- keydown.
- keypress.
- keyup.

*Try this code:*

```
$(document).on('keyup',
     '.select2-search__field',
     function (e) {       
        alert($(this).val());
     }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
$('.items-input').on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function (e) {
    //your code
});
```